# Pixel location while passing mouse

Tags: matlab, position, location, pixel

I have been Googling for a while for that. If I `imshow()` some image, when I pass the mouse on that image, how can I at the same time view the pixel locations `(x,y)`?

Thanks.

Comment: after imshow the image, type `impixelinfo` in the command window.

Comment: Great. see more details in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When typing `impixelinfo` in the command window, you'll get the current figure pop-up, and the x-y location of the mouse appears in the left bottom corner, also with the value of the pixel.

Note that while in matlab language`image(a,b)` means the pixel in row `a` and column `b`, the notation in the `impixelinfo` is according to x-y axis, so `(a,b)` there will represent the pixel in column `a` (x axis) and row `b` (reversed y axis).